# Почему вместо названий файлов отображаются стили?

Tags: css, css3

При вводе ссылки не показываются названия документов, хотя плагин `AutoFileName` установлен

[image: Скриншот 3]

[image: Скриншот]

[image: Скриншот2]

Comment: Это вообще что?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, что за приложение вы используете и какой результат хотите получить.

Comment: Sublime Text 3. Должен появится фон на сайте

Comment: что указано в настройках плагина? активирован ли плагин?

Comment: "afn_use_project_root": false
"afn_proj_root": "../"
"afn_valid_scopes":["string","css","sass","less","scss"]
"afn_template_languages": false
"afn_blacklist_scopes":["string.regexp.js"]
"afn_insert_dimensions": true
"afn_insert_width_first": false
"afn_use_keybinding": false  вроде активирован. Я скачал готовый проект там все нормально, а в тех что создаю я не работает